# Characteristic polynomial of the symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

I tried to solve the following example:

*Find all symmetric and real matrices A with the characteristic polynomial:*$$ p_A(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - 4 \lambda + 4  $$

I have tried to approach this with diagonal matrices that have roots of the polynomial (or its n-th square root) on the diagonal. Yet this seems unsatisfactory. What do I miss?

Thank you in advance for any clue.

Comment: Why does it seem unsatisfactory?

Comment: I have not been told - yet I cannot come to the reason why. I got this result as incorrect.

Comment: The matrix must be diagonalisable and $2\times2$. The characteristic polynomial is basis invariant. The polynomial is $(\lambda-2)^2$ so the answer is: all matrices similar to: $$\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @FShrike surely a matrix similar to $2I$ must *be* $2I$. Maybe that is what was missing in OP's answer too? The answer should've been: there is only *one* such matrix, namely $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Every (real) symmetric is diagonalizable (even orthogonally diagonalizable), by the Spectral Theorem (or one of its resulting sub-theorems), thus your assumption that your matrix is diagonal is completely correct, and since similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial then ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is easy beacuse the degree of the polynomial says you that the matrix has order $2$ and the symmetric property says you that it is similar to a diagonal matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
  \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus

$$\begin{cases}
\lambda_1+\lambda_2=4\\
\lambda_1\lambda_2=4
\end{cases}$$

That tells you $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=2$.

Hence the symmetric matrices having that characteristic polynomial are $B(2I)B^{-1}=2I$.
Thus there is only one, $2I$.